# has_child and has_parent not returning results

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-7

I went through the following links before pasting the ques

[Elasticsearch has_child returning no results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62413359/elasticsearch-has-child-returning-no-results)

[ElasticSearch 7.3 has_parent/has_child don't return any hits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59185858/elasticsearch-7-3-has-parent-has-child-dont-return-any-hits)

[ES documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-has-parent-query.html)

I created a simple mapping with `text_doc` as the parent and `flag_doc` as the child.

```
{
  "doc_index_ap3" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "domain" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "email_text" : {
          "type" : "text"
        },
        "id" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "my_join_field" : {
          "type" : "join",
          "eager_global_ordinals" : true,
          "relations" : {
            "text_doc" : "flag_doc"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The query with `parent_id` works fine & returns 1 doc as expected

```
GET doc_index_ap3/_search
{
  "query": {
      "parent_id": {
        "type": "flag_doc",
        "id":"f0d2cb3c-bf4b-11eb-9f67-93a282921115"
      }
  }
}
```

But none of the below queries return any results.

```
GET doc_index_ap3/_search
{
  "query": {
    "has_parent": {
      "parent_type": "text_doc",
      "query": {
        "match_all": {
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

GET doc_index_ap3/_search
{
  "query": {
    "has_child": {
      "type": "flag_doc",
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be some issue in the way you have indexed the parent and child documents. Refer to this official documentation, to know more about [parent-child relationship](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/parent-join.html%27)

Adding a working example using the same index mapping as given in the question above

**Parent document in the text_doc context**

```
PUT /index-name/_doc/1

{
  "domain": "ab",
  "email_text": "ab",
  "id": "ab",
  "my_join_field": {
    "name": "text_doc"
  }
}
```

**Child document**

```
PUT /index-name/_doc/2?routing=1&refresh



 {
  "domain": "cs",
  "email_text": "cs",
  "id": "cs",
  "my_join_field": {
    "name": "flag_doc",
    "parent": "1"
  }
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "has_parent": {
      "parent_type": "text_doc",
      "query": {
        "match_all": {
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "67731507",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_routing": "1",
        "_source": {
          "domain": "cs",
          "email_text": "cs",
          "id": "cs",
          "my_join_field": {
            "name": "flag_doc",
            "parent": "1"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
```

---

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "has_child": {
      "type": "flag_doc",
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "67731507",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "domain": "ab",
          "email_text": "ab",
          "id": "ab",
          "my_join_field": {
            "name": "text_doc"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Hey! Yeah, I am using a python script to index the docs. The structure of parent doc is
`
parent_doc = {
        "id":"1",
        "email_text":"",
        'my_join_field': {"name":"text_doc"}
}
`
And that of child doc
`
child_doc = {
        "id":"child_1",
        "domain":"abc.com",
        "routing":"",
        'my_join_field': {
            "name":"flag_doc",
            "parent":"1"
        }
}
`

Comment: I populate `routing` with parent's `id`

Comment: Oh actually, I just noticed that in your query for indexing child doc you have used `"parent": "1"` which is the `_id` of parent doc and not `id`. Let me update my script & try again